# Jenkins : Build Freestyle job from a pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I've I have 2 Jenkins Job: A freestyle job 'A' and Pipeline 'B'

I want to build 'A' job inside 'B'  in one of my stages.

I've tried building it this way inside my jenkins file :

```
stage('Running A') {
    agent none
     
    steps{
        build job: 'A'
    }
}
```

but it doesn't work. I get :

> no item named 'A' found

Is there anyone who's familiar with this kind of method please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `build job: 'A'` I've changed it to   `build 'A'`

That's how it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that you're not using the correct job name.

Get the job name of `A` by `REST API` at the bottom left or updating the script to run `echo env.JOB_NAME && exit 1` temporarily.